# how to access file or folders from azure ml service dataset?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Currently I am working on azure ml service where I have dataset in azure ml named as 'voice_recognition_expreimnt'.
I access this dataset by this code:

```
file_dataset =  Dataset.get_by_name(workspace=ws, name='voice_recognition_expreimnt')
```

Now I want to access all file or folders in the dataset. So how can I traverse through all path in my dataset. I search a lot but I can't find any solution. So please help me

Comment: Is it a `TabularDataset` or `FileDataset`? What version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on if you plan on doing work inside of compute instance notebook directly or submitting Runs via a `ScriptRun`, `Estimator`.

### Direct access

You can use [`.download()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.file_dataset.filedataset?view=azure-ml-py#download-target-path-none--overwrite-false-) to put the files on the machine on which you're currently working.

```py
file_dataset.download()
```

### Consumption via training runs

Below is a common patern in the Azure ML SDK to make datasets available to `Runs`, `Estimators`, PythonScriptSteps` and the like. All of these classes make it especially easy to run your code on your dataset on many compute targets.

```py
src = ScriptRunConfig(
    source_directory=source_directory, 
    script='dummy_train.py',
    arguments=[file_dataset.as_named_input('input').as_mount(),
               output
        ]
)

exp = Experiment(ws, 'ScriptRun_sample')
run = exp.submit(config=src)
```

Here are a few tutorials that go into more detail.

1. [Creating and using a `FileDataset` within an `Estimator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-datasets#create-a-filedataset)
2. [How to use ScriptRun with data input and output](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial/scriptrun-with-data-input-output/how-to-use-scriptrun.ipynb) notebook (the entire ["datasets tutorial" folder](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial) is a great example.